# How to output any/all Audio from applications etc to two monitors simultaneously

Tags: audio, multiple-monitors, audio-output

I have been attempting to find the solution for a few months and have only reached deadends. Many people seem to have achieved it via windows built in audio mixer however after following the steps to a T certain options are just unavailable/ non existent on my rig. I was playing around with a program called audio router but due to it being dead in the water in terms of updates it is no longer working at all.

Comment: I can't test this as I'm on Mac, but the new go-to for Windows seems to be [Voicemeeter](https://www.vb-audio.com) They do several products from simple internal virtual cabling to full audio mixers.

Comment: to clarify: you want the same audio out of 2 separate monitors' speakers. For example, 1 audio mix output via both hdmi to the built-in speakers on each monitor simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, just use windows embedded mixer.
My default device is Speaker. I added headphones in example

windows mixer

[image: windows mixer]